# Breakdown / Documentation of a SQL Query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a very large, complex, and undocumented database. I have a task to provide a document which would show which tables and columns have been used for all stored procedures, functions, etc.

According to my research majority of queries will have the similar format to this:

```
SELECT u.FirstName , u.LastName, a.AccountNumber
FROM Username u
LEFT JOIN Account a
ON a.UserID = u.UserID
```

~90% of tables and columns will have aliases.

Further, I do have a table with 2 columns - function/sproc name, and its SQL code.

I am looking for a method (preferably SQL, but can be C#) which would output the following results for the above SQL code:

- Username - FirstName
- Username - LastName
- Username - UserID
- Account - UserID
- Account - AccountNumber

What would be the best approach to achieve this? I have tried to join each SQL code cell with INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS but I get inaccurate results, say when column name appears in the COLUMNS table, but was not actually used for that specific table in the SQL code cell.

Thanks

Comment: I am a bit confused, but I am also rather dense.  Are you looking to bypass looping through a result set by using a method that does it for you?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to look at the dependencies on the stored procedure/function that you are looking at?

Take a look at https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1768/identifying-object-dependencies-in-sql-server/

e.g. if the procedure name is dbo.myproc, something like the below

```
SELECT '* ' + referenced_entity_name + ' - ' + referenced_minor_name
FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities ('dbo.myproc', 'OBJECT')
WHERE referenced_minor_name is not null;
```